# Using find_or_create_by to seed a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, model

I'm currently in the process of creating a seeds file in my app and wanted to ensure that no duplicates were created using `find_or_create_by` suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4570201). I'm using `find_or_create_by_name` but get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `find_or_create_by_name' for #<Class:0x007fa9680cb688>
```

This is what I'm using in the seeds file

```
Genre.find_or_create_by_name([
    {name: "Alternative"}, 
    {name: "Country"}, 
    {name: "Electronic"}
    ])
```

Also worth asking. If I had a uniqueness validator for a model's name would `find_or_create_by` still be necessary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Newer versions of Rails use a slightly different syntax:

```
Genre.find_or_create_by(name: 'Alternative')
```

`find_or_create_by` does not support adding multiple records at a time so you'll have to construct an array of hashes and call `find_or_create_by` mutliple times:

```
hashes = [
  {name: "Alternative"}, 
  {name: "Country"}, 
  {name: "Electronic"}
]

hashes.each do |hash|
  Genre.find_or_create_by(hash)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use something like this:

```
User.where(name: "Alice").first_or_create
```

This will return the first user with the name "Alice", or if there isn't one it'll create and return a new user with name "Alice".

This doesn't mean you can't have multiple users with the name "Alice", because if they were in the database before, you'll only find the first one.